# Find the point on the line segment joining $P_1(1, 4,-3)$ and $P_2(1, 5,-1)$ that is $2/3$ of the way from $P_1$ to $P_2$

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

[image: finding coordinates]

I had used the distance formula $d(p_1,p_2)=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}$ and got $\sqrt5$ and multiply $\sqrt 5$ by $2/3$ I get $1.5$.

Now, how can I get the coordinates $x,y,z$?

Comment: Hint: the midpoint for example is $1/2$ of the way, and is $\,(P_1+P_2)/2\,$. Find a similar expression for the point that is at $2/3$ of the way, instead. You don't need to explicitly calculate any distances.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is  $$P_1 + (2/3)(P_2 -P_1)$$

You check and see which one is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We need the parametric equation for the segment that is

$$P(t)=P_1+t(P_2-P_1)=(1,4,-3)+t(0,1,2)$$

indeed note that

- $P(0)=P_1$
- $P(1)=P_2$

and then take the value $t=\frac23$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use proportional triangles instead. If a point is $\frac23$ of the way from $P_1$ to $P_2$, then its $x$-coordinate is $\frac23$ of the way between the $x$-coordinates of $P_1$ and $P_2$, and so on.